# IOS Beta 13 CoreNFC NDEF Lock NFC tag with writeLock()

Tags: core-nfc

We have been successfully writing to NFC tags using Beta 13, but have had no luck with trying to lock them using the writeLock() function.  After execution we get back a result of nil but it is definitely not locking.  Any clues or has anyone managed to get this work as yet?

Code is extremely straight forward (but might have done something stupid!) - Trying on different variations of a NXP NTAG213 tag:

```
if (self.lockTag) {
                            // locking required also
                            os_log("Tag needs to be locked")
                            tag.writeLock() { (error: Error?) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    os_log("LOCK FAILED!!")
                                    session.alertMessage = "Lock failed try again"
                                    session.invalidate()
                                } else {
                                    session.alertMessage = "Write and Lock successful"
                                    session.invalidate()
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            // only writing
                            os_log("Tag is unlocked")
                            session.alertMessage = "Write successful!"
                            session.invalidate()
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I was being stupid and missed out the some returns. This codes works perfectly and locks NFC tags:

```
if (self.lockTag) {
                            // locking required also
                            os_log("Tag needs to be locked")
                            tag.writeLock() { (error: Error?) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    os_log("LOCK FAILED!!")
                                    session.alertMessage = "Lock failed try again"
                                    session.invalidate()
                                    return
                                } else {
                                    session.alertMessage = "Write and Lock successful"
                                    session.invalidate()
                                    return
                                }
                            }
                            return
```